# Wide to long binary matrix adding counts

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, reshape

I want to go from wide to long format but keeping the count value and factorizing the columns. I have this:

```
variable   LF1   LF2   LF3   LF4   LF5   Counts
A           1     0     0     0     0      5 
A           1     0     1     0     0      1    
B           1     0     0     1     0      3 
B           1     0     0     0     1      2 
B           1     0     0     0     0      1 
C           1     0     0     0     0      8 
D           1     1     0     0     0      6 
D           1     0     1     0     0      4
```

And I want the following:

```
 variable   factor    count
    A         F1        6
    A         F3        1
    B         F1        6
    B         F4        3
    B         F5        2
    C         F1        8
    D         F1        10
    D         F2        6
    D         F3        4
```

This implies that data is simultaneously transformed to long while summing up the counts.
I have tried with all combinations I can think of in reshape2 but I ran out of ideas e.g.

```
data_grouped <- reshape2::melt(data, id.vars=c("variable"))
data_grouped <- reshape2::melt(data, id.vars=c("variable","LF1","LF2","LF3","LF4","LF5"))
```

Also I see that I can get something similar by concatenating the following:

```
data %>% group_by(variable, LF1) %>% summarise(sum(counts))
data %>% group_by(variable, LF2) %>% summarise(sum(counts))
```

But this is very inefficient and not the ideal solution, therefore I'd really appreciate a hand on this.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your data? See instructions at teh top of the r page here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is called `df`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("LF"),
               names_to = "factor") %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  group_by(variable, factor) %>%
  summarize(count = sum(Counts)) %>%
  mutate(factor = str_remove(factor, "L")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

gives:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  variable factor count
  <chr>    <chr>  <int>
1 A        F1         6
2 A        F3         1
3 B        F1         6
4 B        F4         3
5 B        F5         2
6 C        F1         8
7 D        F1        10
8 D        F2         6
9 D        F3         4
```

Comment: Would still be great if you could provide a reproducible example above just in case someone wants to help and finds a potential better solution.